# Google Pay Button Not Rendering On The Checkout Page Of Payment Link Of Stripe

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-checkout

I'm using **Stripe's** **Payment links,** and I've activated the **Google Pay** and **Apple Pay** button but it's not showing on the checkout page.

I activated both buttons; **Google Pay** and **Apple Pay**, but they are not showing on the main checkout page. There is also no documentation solving this problem exactly.

Please help me by solving this problem.

Comment: What browser are you trying it in? They won't show up in Firefox.

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Show us the page and your code, in that case. Apple Pay won't show up in Chrome. Do you see the test button show up in https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button ? Is there anything in the browser's developer console?

Comment: The method I'm using is a payment link, that's no code

Comment: Apple Pay will only show if you're using Safari on iOS or macOS. Google Pay will only show in Chrome if you log in to your Google account with saved cards on Google Pay app (not Chrome browser). For more requirement details to show Apple Pay and Google Pay, you can refer to the doc here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#html-js-testing

Comment: That's not working